# CompileTimeError: Type arguments in partial instantiations must be instantiated and are therefore not allowed to depend on type parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to call `listenEventReducer` I get this strange error. The method knows the type, still not sure where I go wrong.

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

enum ObjectChangeType { added, modified, removed }

typedef UpdateItem<T extends ListenEventItem> = T Function(T oldItem, T newItem);

T _defaultUpdate<T extends ListenEventItem>(T oldItem, T newItem) => newItem;

abstract class ListenEventItem {
  String get id;

  ObjectChangeType get changeType;
}

abstract class ListenEvent<T extends ListenEventItem> {
  List<T> get data;

  Map<ObjectChangeType, List<T>> get typedData {
    return data.fold(
      <ObjectChangeType, List<T>>{},
      (Map<ObjectChangeType, List<T>> map, T element) {
        map[element.changeType] = (map[element.changeType] ?? <T>[])..add(element);

        return map;
      },
    );
  }
}

Map<String, T> listenEventReducer<T extends ListenEventItem>(Map<String, T> state, ListenEvent<T> action,
    [UpdateItem<T> update = _defaultUpdate]) {
  update ??= _defaultUpdate;
  final Map<String, T> b = Map<String, T>.from(state);

  for (ObjectChangeType type in ObjectChangeType.values) {
    final List<T> data = action.typedData[type];
    if (data == null || data.isEmpty) {
      continue;
    }

    if (type == ObjectChangeType.added) {
      for (T item in data) {
        b[item.id] == item;
      }
    } else if (type == ObjectChangeType.modified) {
      for (T item in data) {
        b[item.id] = update(b[item.id], item);
      }
    } else if (type == ObjectChangeType.removed) {
      final List<String> ids = data.map((T it) => it.id).toList();
      b.removeWhere((String id, _) => ids.contains(id));
    }
  }

  return b;
}

class Data extends ListenEventItem {
  Data(this.id, this.changeType, this.metadata);

  final String metadata;

  @override
  final String id;

  @override
  final ObjectChangeType changeType;
}

class DataEvent extends ListenEvent<Data> {
  DataEvent(this.data);

  @override
  final List<Data> data;
}

void main() {
  final List<Data> items = List<Data>();
  items.add(Data('0', ObjectChangeType.added, 'a'));
  items.add(Data('1', ObjectChangeType.added, 'b'));
  items.add(Data('0', ObjectChangeType.removed, 'a'));
  items.add(Data('2', ObjectChangeType.added, 'c'));
  items.add(Data('1', ObjectChangeType.modified, 'd'));
  items.add(Data('3', ObjectChangeType.added, 'e'));
  final DataEvent event = DataEvent(items);

  final Map<String, Data> state = Map<String, Data>();
  final Map<String, Data> newState = listenEventReducer<Data>(state, event);

  expect(newState, isNotNull);
  expect(newState.length, 3);
  expect(newState['0'], isNull);
  expect(newState['1'].metadata, 'd');
  expect(newState['2'].metadata, 'c');
  expect(newState['3'].metadata, 'e');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `typedef` and the function types `_defaultUpdate` doesn't match exactly and provide full information to compiler about type generics.

When initializing `[UpdateItem<T> update = _defaultUpdate]`, the compiler expects type `T` for UpdateItem but it doesn't know if `_defaultUpdate` is actually returning `T` where `T extends ListenEventItem`, the `_defaultUpdate` can return any type `S` where `S extends ListenEventItem`.

Say for instance you have two classes extending `ListenEventItem`

```
class A extends ListenEventItem {}
```

and

```
class B extends ListenEventItem {}
```

Now, the `_defaultUpdate` function can return either `A` or `B` when no generic argument passed. 
And when you try to initialize it like

```
UpdateItem<A> update = _defaultUpdate
```

compiler doesn't know if `_defaultUpdate` returns `A` or `B` making it fail at compile time.

---

You can fix this making the typedef function accept generic arguments, that way compiler knows to expect any class that extends `ListenEventItem`

Example:

```
typedef UpdateItem = T Function<T extends ListenEventItem>(T oldItem, T newItem);

T _defaultUpdate<T extends ListenEventItem>(T oldItem, T newItem) => newItem;
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

enum ObjectChangeType { added, modified, removed }

typedef UpdateItem = T Function<T extends ListenEventItem>(T oldItem, T newItem);

T _defaultUpdate<T extends ListenEventItem>(T oldItem, T newItem) => newItem;

abstract class ListenEventItem {
  String get id;

  ObjectChangeType get changeType;
}

abstract class ListenEvent<T extends ListenEventItem> {
  List<T> get data;

  Map<ObjectChangeType, List<T>> get typedData {
    return data.fold(
      <ObjectChangeType, List<T>>{},
      (Map<ObjectChangeType, List<T>> map, T element) {
        map[element.changeType] = (map[element.changeType] ?? <T>[])
          ..add(element);

        return map;
      },
    );
  }
}

Map<String, T> listenEventReducer<T extends ListenEventItem>(
    Map<String, T> state, ListenEvent<T> action,
    [UpdateItem update = _defaultUpdate]) {
  update ??= _defaultUpdate;
  final Map<String, T> b = Map<String, T>.from(state);

  for (ObjectChangeType type in ObjectChangeType.values) {
    final List<T> data = action.typedData[type];
    if (data == null || data.isEmpty) {
      continue;
    }

    if (type == ObjectChangeType.added) {
      for (T item in data) {
        b[item.id] = item;
      }
    } else if (type == ObjectChangeType.modified) {
      for (T item in data) {
        b[item.id] = update(b[item.id], item);
      }
    } else if (type == ObjectChangeType.removed) {
      final List<String> ids = data.map((T it) => it.id).toList();
      b.removeWhere((String id, _) => ids.contains(id));
    }
  }

  return b;
}

class Data extends ListenEventItem {
  Data(this.id, this.changeType, this.metadata);

  final String metadata;

  @override
  final String id;

  @override
  final ObjectChangeType changeType;
}

class DataEvent extends ListenEvent<Data> {
  DataEvent(this.data);

  @override
  final List<Data> data;
}

void main() {
  final List<Data> items = List<Data>();
  items.add(Data('0', ObjectChangeType.added, 'a'));
  items.add(Data('1', ObjectChangeType.added, 'b'));
  items.add(Data('0', ObjectChangeType.removed, 'a'));
  items.add(Data('2', ObjectChangeType.added, 'c'));
  items.add(Data('1', ObjectChangeType.modified, 'd'));
  items.add(Data('3', ObjectChangeType.added, 'e'));
  final DataEvent event = DataEvent(items);

  final Map<String, Data> state = Map<String, Data>();
  final Map<String, Data> newState = listenEventReducer<Data>(state, event);

  test('Test', () {
    expect(newState, isNotNull);
    expect(newState.length, 3);
    expect(newState['0'], isNull);
    expect(newState['1'].metadata, 'd');
    expect(newState['2'].metadata, 'c');
    expect(newState['3'].metadata, 'e');
  });
}
```

Comment: Raj, you are the best. I'm fully impressed. :D

Comment: Thanks @RazvanCristianLung! I'm just returning the favor, hope you remember helping me master redux :P

Comment: Note that the explanation of the error is somewhat incorrect - the correct explanation is that default parameter values must be *constant*, which means they can't depend on any type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need to declare the parameter as `[UpdateItem update = _defaultUpdate]`, the statement `update ??= _defaultUpdate;` ensures that `update` gets the desired value anyway. So just using `[UpdateItem update]` solves the problem that the default value isn't constant.

The mismatch between the type `T Function(T, T)` of `update` (where `T` is a given type, received as an actual type argument by `listenEventReducer` at the invocation) and the type `T Function<T extends ListenEventItem>(T , T)` of `_defaultUpdate` (where `T` is declared by the function type itself) is resolved by 'generic function instantiation'. Here's a simple example of that:

```dart
X foo<X>(X x) => x;

main() {
  int Function(int) f = foo;
  print(f(42));
  // But `f('Hello!')` is a type error.
}
```

The point is that `foo` is a generic function, but it can receive its actual type argument(s) *as a function* by inference, and the result is a function of type `int Function(int)` (that is, a non-generic function). It will accept an `int` and return an `int`, and this discipline is enforced even if you call it dynamically (e.g., `(f as dynamic)('Hello!')` will throw); so the resulting function object is a proper `int Function(int)`, not just `foo` under a different name.

If you want to emulate the same thing explicitly then you can write a wrapper function:

```dart
X foo<X>(X x) => x;

main() {
  int Function(int) f = (int x) => foo<int>(x);
  print(f(42));
  // But `f('Hello!')` is a type error.
}
```